# File editor- counturing ppm file

Tags: c

I'm making an image editor for pgm and ppm files and i have problem with one function. The contouring which should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu5KV.jpg). This was made by the function: convert -convolve 0,0,0,0,-2,1,0,1,0 picture.ppm pictureRes.ppm in terminal. Unfortunately my program gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCAqj.jpg)

```
void konturowanie(t_obraz *obraz,int odczytano) // odczytano tells us with what sort of file we are dealing ppm=3 pgm else
{
  if (odczytano == 3)
  {
for (int j = 0; j < 3*obraz->wymx; j++)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < obraz->wymy; i++)
  {
   obraz->piksele[j * (obraz->wymy) + i] = (abs(obraz->piksele[(j+1) * (obraz->wymy) + i] - obraz->piksele[j * (obraz->wymy) + i])) + (abs(obraz->piksele[j * (obraz->wymy) + i+1] - obraz->piksele[j * (obraz->wymy) + i]));
   }
}
}
else
{
  for (int i = 0; i < obraz->wymx; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < obraz->wymy; j++)
     {
       obraz->piksele[j * (obraz->wymx) + i] = (abs(obraz->piksele[(j+1) * (obraz->wymx) + i] - obraz->piksele[j * (obraz->wymx) + i])) + (abs(obraz->piksele[j * (obraz->wymx) + i+1] - obraz->piksele[j * (obraz->wymx) + i]));
   } 
  }
 }
}
```

`

```
typedef struct //and struck in which this is stored
{
 int wymx, wymy, szarosci;
 int *piksele; 
 } t_obraz;
```

The code is working fine for pgm files but it doesn't for ppm,I cant see any mistakes and im stuck, thanks for help in advance